# Como exportar datos de un Excel a una base de datos Mysql?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, excel, mysql-workbench

Es posible mover unas tablas que tengo en excel file .xlsx a MySQL? Son tablas algo grandes. Como 300 columnas y 5000 rows. Espero me puedan ayudar o pasar info donde pueda leer acerca de esto.

Gracias!!

Comment: Puedes hacer un script en Php con https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## solución 1

**Des de Excel nativamente directo a Mysql**. No es complejo mas allá de seguir los tutoriales de ayuda de excel. Pero te puede dificultar el tema de los schemas de la tabla si ya existen. Deja el nombre de las columnas idéntico al de las tablas ya creadas. Ahí tienes un manual oficial con imágenes. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-for-excel/en/mysql-for-excel-export.html

## solución 2

**Des de Excel exportas a `csv` para posteriormente importar a `mysql`.**

Para mi es la recomendada:

1. Menú archivo > guardar como > `abc.csv` formato fichero `csv`.
2. Entra consola mysql. Dedujo por tu pregunta que des de windows.

   1. menú ejecutar : `mysql.exe –u<username> –p`
3. ejecuta el código siguiente modificando si es el caso la configuración de carácter final de campo, delimitador de campo, nombre de la tabla `abc`, ignorar lineas si hay `headers` ( puedes borrarla en caso contrario), **e indicando las columnas a importar** tal y como están en el ejemplo `col1,col2`:

   ```sql
   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'abc.csv' INTO TABLE abc
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
   ENCLOSED BY '"' 
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
   IGNORE 1 LINES
   (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5...);
   ```

Sin mas detalles en la pregunta, hasta aquí puedo aportar.

Comment: Gracias! esto me ayudo!